# Simplified multiple condition check

Tags: java

I am having a method that checks multiple conditions and returns a boolean value. wanted to check if there is any way to refactor the code.

```
public static void isEligible(Response response) {
  boolean isAttr1Set = isAttr1Set(response);
  boolean isAttr2Set = isAttr2Set(response);
  boolean isAttr3Set = isAttr3Set(response);
  boolean isAttr4Set = isAttr4Set(response);
  Logger.log("Attr1 " + isAttr1Set);
  Logger.log("Attr2 " + isAttr2Set);
  Logger.log("Attr3 " + isAttr3Set);
  Logger.log("Attr4 " + isAttr4Set);
  return isAttr1Set() && isAttr2Set() && isAttr3Set() && isAttr4Set();
}
```

**UPDATE**
My bad missed the return type and use of variables in the original post, my question is how can I refactor this to code to call further methods only if the previous method returns true and also logs each attribute value? I want to avoid using multiple inner if conditions.

Original Code

```
public static boolean isEligible(Response response) {
  boolean isAttr1Set = isAttr1Set(response);
  boolean isAttr2Set = isAttr2Set(response);
  boolean isAttr3Set = isAttr3Set(response);
  boolean isAttr4Set = isAttr4Set(response);
  Logger.log("Attr1 " + isAttr1Set);
  Logger.log("Attr2 " + isAttr2Set);
  Logger.log("Attr3 " + isAttr3Set);
  Logger.log("Attr4 " + isAttr4Set);
  return isAttr1Set && isAttr2Set && isAttr3Set && isAttr4Set;
}
```

Comment: Having a working method as a starting point would be helpful, before thinking about refactoring the code. You can’t return values from a `void` method and there’s no consistency between your method invocation `isAttr1Set(response)`, the variable `isAttr1Set`, and the sudden appearance of another method `isAttr1Set()` (the same for all other attributes).

Comment: You don't need to keep both versions of your code. You can just put the most recent version. The problem here is the logging, you cannot log the method calls, and also avoid the method call. If you don't need the logging then Nikolai's answer will do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to avoid calling next method only if previous call returned true, then you should chain your calls.

One option is to use short circuit evaluation:

```
return isAttr1Set(response) && isAttr2Set(response) && isAttr3Set(response) && isAttr4Set(response);
```

here `isAttr2Set` won't be called if `isAttr1Set` returned `false`, and so on for other methods in this chain.

Another option is to prepare list of method references and use `Stream#allMatch` (which is also a short circuit operation hence it will terminate after first `false` evaluated).

```java
boolean allAttributesSet = Stream.<Function<Response, Boolean>>of(
        this::isAttr1Set,
        this::isAttr2Set,
        this::isAttr3Set,
        this::isAttr4Set
).allMatch(func -> func.apply(response));
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you pull the code out before the return (Looks like you only use it for debugging) then that code look pretty tight to me! Also, note that you are returning a boolean on a void method BUT this wouldn't make it past a compile!

Answer (score 0):

Change `void` to `boolean` for your return type. Next, give your local variable names different ones than that of the methods. Lastly, use the already retrieved values in your boolean check instead calling the methods again:

```
public static boolean isEligible(Response response) {
  boolean is1Set = isAttr1Set(response);
  boolean is2Set = isAttr2Set(response);
  boolean is3Set = isAttr3Set(response);
  boolean is4Set = isAttr4Set(response);
  Logger.log("Attr1 " + is1Set);
  Logger.log("Attr2 " + is2Set);
  Logger.log("Attr3 " + is3Set);
  Logger.log("Attr4 " + is4Set);
  return is1Set && is2Set && is3Set && is4Set;
}
```